# editing the display of an existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How to make a data upload request correctly in order to get data from the table in the form I expect?

I have this table:

[image]

But am expecting this:

[image]

Comment: Have a look on GROUP_CONCAT, see for example https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this purpose:

```sql
SELECT 
  ID, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(TitleUid) As TitleUid, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(Title) AS Title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(types) AS types 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY ID;

-- ID   TitleUid        Title                   types
-- 1    asd,dsa,ssd     title1,title2,title3    typeA,typeB,typeC
-- 2    asd,ssf         title1,title2           typeB,typeC
-- 3    ssf,xcv,zxc     title1,title2,title3    typeA,typeB,typeC
```

Comment: sorry, 
I need to convert a row to columns

Comment: Take the time to try `GROUP_CONCAT`, as the output is the exact one you mentioned. If this does not answer your question, please clarify it, add what you're tried and some sample data for us to help you.